# Tags in new tabs overlaps the learn more link on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

When you search for certain tags (tags with a lot of questions) to enter into a custom new tab. it overlaps the learn more link that comes up on hover.

[image: Learn More Overlapping]

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in most cases now. Replaced 'learn more' with an icon due to tight spacing.